# Why no speedup with more than one thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedimage

I'm creating a toy program in java using synchronized block. I have n "Pixelator" threads  which pick a random pixel in a 1000x1000 image and assign it to the color of the Pixelator. Each pixel can only be assigned once. I write to a bufferedImage using a wrapper class that uses a synchronized method to write to the image. However, when I test with more than 1 thread, I do not see a speedup. Do you have a hint as to why that would be?

Relavant Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class q2 {

    // The image constructed
    public static BufferedImage img;

    // Image dimensions; you could also retrieve these from the img object.
    public static int width;
    public static int height;

    // simplified method for stack overflow example
    public static int rgbFromN(int n) {
        return -16755216;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        try {
            // arg 0 is the width
            width = 1000;
            // arg 1 is the height
            height = 1000;
            // arg 2 is the number of threads
            int nt = 1;

            // create an image and initialize it to all 0's
            img = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            synchronizedIMG simg = new synchronizedIMG(img);
            for (int i=0;i<width;i++) {
                for (int j=0;j<height;j++) {
                    img.setRGB(i,j,0);
                }
            }


            Thread[] threads = new Thread[nt];
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
                threads[i] = new Thread(new Pixelator(rgbFromN(i),width,height,((width*height)/nt),simg));    
                threads[i].start();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {   
                threads[i].join();
            }

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Time(ms): " + (endTime-startTime));

            // Write out the image
            File outputfile = new File("outputimage.png");
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR " +e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Pixelator implements Runnable {
    int color;
    int width;
    int height;
    int numPixels;
    int currentPixels = 0;
    synchronizedIMG simg;

    public Pixelator(int color, int width, int height,int numPixels, synchronizedIMG simg){
        this.color = color;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.numPixels = numPixels;
        this.simg = simg;
    }

    public void run() {
        int randomX = 0;
        int randomY = 0;
        boolean success = false;

        while(currentPixels < numPixels){
            randomX = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * (width));
            randomY = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * (height));
            success = simg.setColor(color, randomX, randomY);
            if(success){
                currentPixels++;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}

class synchronizedIMG{
    BufferedImage img;

    public synchronizedIMG(BufferedImage img){
        this.img = img;
    }

    public synchronized boolean setColor(int color, int x, int y){
        if(img.getRGB(x, y) == 0){
            img.setRGB(x, y, color);
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because your setColor is synchronized?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @user2677821 how would I make sure that two threads don't write to the same pixel at the same time without synchronized?

Comment: @user2677821`BufferedImage.setRGB` is also `synchronized` (so same effect, so yes you're right but changing `setColor` doesn't impact this)

Comment: Cut up the image into sections and have each thread only able to paint within that section.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Oh, thanks didn't know.

Comment: @user2677821 unfortunately that would not be a possibility because I need each thread to paint a random pixel in the entire image.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt since BufferedImage.setRGB is synchronized, is there a way at all to fill in an image with multiple threads and see an improvement as the number of working threads increases?

Comment: Only if you don't work on the same BufferedImage from multiple threads - so perhaps like user\d+ suggested, use multiple smaller BufferedImages and recombine them later into one, or if your calculations were more complex than coming up with a random number, you could do the calculations in separate threads but the actual rendering to the image afterwards in one thread.

Comment: Even if you want to paint random pixels in the entire image, you can split it up.  Each thread could generate random locations across the entire image but only paint if the random location fell onto its own subimage. Or it could just limit the random range to its subimage. Of course with this simple example, none of these are going to be much faster than working in a single thread since there is more setup and post-processing involved. But on bigger jobs it could improve performance

Comment: Re, "I need each thread to paint a random pixel in the entire image."

Why?  If there was a faster way to do it where the threads did not work in that way but the resulting image was the same, how would you be able to tell the difference?

Answer (score 0):

It requires a certain amount of time to the machine to manage the threads. In image processing, use two threads instead of one, does not reduce the processing time by 50%, but between 30 % to 40 according to the processing (empirical estimation with the multi-threaded classes of my own java library).

Moreover in your case, you don't do any major processing just simple computation. So it's longer to manage the threads than doing the processing on a single thread. Try to do a big convolution.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you face is that adding more threads will not increase the memory bandwidth of your system.

Your threads do nothing except compute random numbers and write them out to memory.  Adding more threads potentially increases the speed with which you can compute the random numbers, but that probably was pretty fast to begin with.  Math.random() is not a crypto-quality random number generator.  It probably is *very* fast.

Unfortunately, your job isn't done until all of the bytes have been written out to memory.  Your system has only one memory bus, and it can only go so fast.  All of the threads have to contend for that resource.